# c# Dictionary of group perfomance

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, dictionary, lookup-tables

I'm writing a program that needs to use a 
`Dictionary<TKey,groupimplementation<TValue>>`for example what i use is `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>`,every time I need to add items I need to initialize a list of type t if the key doesn't exist and if it does I only need to access the list and add the item.

*is this the most efficient way (in terms of speed) to do this ? or is there any other way ?

one more thing what is the time complexity for checking for the key using `.ContainsKey()`

by the way I can't use iLookup since it's immutable and the only way to initialize one is from the `.tolookup()`methode

Comment: Why? Presumably you're having performance (speed-wise) issues? And you're sure this is the bottle-neck? How many items? How slow? Basically, what?

Comment: This is about the fastest you could do this as long as you don't need to check to ensure the object existence in the list perviously.

Comment: @GrantThomas more than 10 to 100+ million element ,of type <uint,string>

Comment: @ars265 what if I don't have to check for the key existence ?

Comment: I said don't, if you did and I were you, I'd shoot myself in the foot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this the most efficient way (in terms of speed) to do this ? or is
>   there any other way ?

Before adding an item to the list you have to initialize it *(if the list is not already initialized)*. Only looking at your description *(not code)* I can only guess that it is fine. For checking if the key exists, you are using `ContainsKey` which has the `O(1)` complexity.

> what is the time complexity for checking for the key using
>   .ContainsKey()

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey` Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)

> This method approaches an **O(1)** operation.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to access and modify a dictionary's value   is to use it's [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb347013.aspx) method.

So you only need to access it once instead of twice if you first check if it contains a given key.

For example:

```
List<TValue> theList;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(theKey, out theList))
    theList.Add(newItem);
else
    dictionary.Add(theKey, new List<TValue> { newItem });
```

Comment: @Time Schmelter thank you very much both answers were okay to me so I choose by voting currently 3:2 .